# Update manually channel priority in conda

Tags: python, conda

Could not find a way to update conda channel priority manually.
Would like to put those channels as top priority channels :

```
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge
https://anaconda.org/bioconda
```

How to update .condarc manually and where to save the file
if we have many envs ?

Answer (score 3):

See the example `.condarc` file [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/sample-condarc.html?highlight=condarc). Your preferred channels should be at the top of the `channels:` list. So you should do the following

- Edit (or create) `~/.condarc`
- Add the following text at the start of the file

  ```
  channels:
    - conda-forge
    - bioconda
    - <your personal channel or any other channels you want ...>
  ```

Comment: @Tensor You should save the file in your home directory. On *nix type OS (with certain shells, at least bash), this is represented by the shortcut `~` or the environment variable `$HOME`. On Windows >= 7, this is `C:\Users\username`.

Comment: @RussHyde Although the OP wanted information specifically about the `.condarc` file, you could also add the `--append` and `--add` options to the `conda config` command. These, combined with `--remove` provide another effective way of managing channels :-)

Comment: I'd recommend against using the `--append` and `--add` options. The op wanted to set the order-of-preference for channels - the only way to specify this with any clarity is by modifying `.condarc`

Comment: Plus, @Tensor you can put a `.condarc` in the main directory for a given envirnoment if you want a different order-of-preference for different projects